# How to install Janet language on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, janet

Do you know how to install Janet on Ubuntu 20.04?

I've downloaded the latest release Janet 1.10.1 for Linux but it's not explained how to install it on README.

Answer (score 7):

I got my answer :

```
git clone https://github.com/janet-lang/janet.git
cd janet
make -j 4
make test
sudo make install
```

This assumes you have git and a gcc installed.